# How to return index - 1 from set of an array

Tags: javascript, array-map

How to return index - 1 from set of an array.

Ex:

```
Function demo(Id) {

Const ids= [1, 2, 3,4,5] ;
// how can I read current index and return index - 1.
return id;
}

Function demo1 (id) ;
```

Comment: [IndexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) is what you are looking for I think

Comment: But by indexOf how could it return index - 1 value.

Comment: `var index = ids.indexOf(1);
return index-1;`

Comment: FYI: JavaScript is case sensitive. It's `function` and `const`, not `Function` and `Const`.

Comment: But value can be any thing inside the array. Should it will be a map function?

Comment: FYI #2: indexOf return "-1" if it doesn't find the value, so with this code It'll return "-2", you should be aware of it

@TanmoySarkar you can pass everything you like, it just need to be an object, javascript tries to find whatever you pass in the function

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by indexOf function see below...

```
function demo(id) {    
 const ids= [1, 2, 3,4,5] ;
 var index = ids.indexOf(id);
 var res = i - 1;
 return res;
}
```

Comment: I'd can be anything it will return not only 3 everytime.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current index of an element in an array, use the `indexOf()` array method. This method returns -1 when the element you are trying to find does not exist in the array.

```js
let index = null;

function demo(id) {
  const ids= [1, 2, 3,4,5];
  // how can I read current index and return index - 1.
  index = ids.indexOf(id);
  return -1;
}

console.log(demo(1), index);
console.log(demo(2), index);
console.log(demo(3), index);
console.log(demo(4), index);
console.log(demo(5), index);
console.log(demo(6), index);  // -1 because 6 isn't in the array
console.log(demo(0), index);  // -1 because 0 isn't in the array
```

Comment: so what I want to achieve here is to read the current index value and return index - 1 here.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar Well to return -1, just write `return -1`, but that doesn't seem to make sense. Why bother finding the index if you are just going to return -1?

Comment: Because I will get anyone of the value in redux and I have to pass previous value for correct I'd.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar See updated answer which does what you ask.

Comment: Nice... Does this updated value will be available with id? As it will be pass as a parameter in other function.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar In my example, I'm storing the actual index of the passed in `id` in the `index` variable, so you can use that value after the function has completed and it will store the index of the element that was last checked by the function.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I will try this out.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar You're welcome. Please up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current index -1 of each array element, this method does that.

```
function checkId(id){
    const ids= [1, 2, 3,4,5] ;

    // return -1 if element doesn't exist 
    let Indx = ids.indexOf(id) == -1 ? -1 : ids.indexOf(id) -1; 

    //do this if you want the array element
    //let arrEl = ids.indexOf(id) == -1 ? -1 : ids[ids.indexOf(id) -1];

    return Indx;
}

console.log(checkId(3)) // returns 1
console.log(checkId(6)) // returns -1
```